# Error Connecting to Firestore: flutter, MissingPluginException

Tags: firebase, android-studio, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-plugin

[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method DocumentReference#setData on channel plugins.flutter.io/cloud_firestore)

```
 Future<void> _createJob(BuildContext context) async{
    final database = Provider.of<Database>(context);
    await database.createJob(Job(name: 'Bloging', ratePerHour: 10));

  }
```

```
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';

class Job{
  Job({@required this.name, @required this.ratePerHour});
  final String name;
  final int ratePerHour;
  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    return{
      'name': name,
      'ratePerHour': ratePerHour,
    };

  }

}
```

```
               create: (_) => FirestoreDatabase(uid: user.uid),
               child: JobsPage());
```

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:time_tracker/app/models/jobs.dart';
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:time_tracker/servises/api_path.dart';

abstract class Database {
  Future<void> createJob (Job job);
}
class FirestoreDatabase implements Database {
  FirestoreDatabase({@required this.uid}) : assert(uid != null);
  final String uid;

  Future<void> createJob (Job job) async {
    final path = APIPAth.job(uid, 'job_abc');
    final documentReference = Firestore.instance.document(path);
    await documentReference.setData(job.toMap());
  }
}
```

```
  static String job (String uid, String jobId) => '/users/$uid/jobs/$jobId';
}
```

Comment: can you add code where you are working with firebase. if you added package while your app was running then try flutter clean and then again run flutter run.

Comment: nothing happened on running comands:- flutter clean & flutter run

Comment: can you add code?

Comment: added the code ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the firestore plugin to `pubspec.yaml` file:

```
dependencies:
  cloud_firestore: ^0.13.5
```

Then execute the following:

> From the terminal: Run flutter pub get.

OR

> From Android Studio/IntelliJ: Click Packages get in the action ribbon at the top of pubspec.yaml.
>
> From VS Code: Click Get Packages located in right side of the action ribbon at the top of pubspec.yaml.

---

In your code change:

```
 final documentReference = Firestore.instance.document(path);
    await documentReference.setData(job.toMap());
```

into this:

```
 final documentReference = Firestore.instance.collection(path);
    await documentReference.add(job.toMap());
```

In firestore you have:

> collection->document->collection->document

If you want to add data to a `collection`, then you need to use the `add()` method which will create a random document id for and add the data.

Comment: what are you getting?

Comment: [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method DocumentReference#setData on channel plugins.flutter.io/cloud_firestore)

Comment: Im not using `setData` in my code, please check the edit again, you need to use `add()`

Comment: nothing changed in the error its still the same @PeterHaddad

Comment: do  flutter clean & flutter run if it didnt work, close the ide, open it again, remove the app from your phone and run it agian

Comment: please mark the answer as correct since it helps you, thank you!